# Bad substitution Bash: how to write a heredoc to a dynamically created file (variable)?

Tags: php, bash, shell

I am about to generate a lot of surveys in php.

I'm using Bash to add some kind of automation with the `cat` command. So I use Bash to generate `.php` files.

To add a new survey, my Bash script counts the files in the survey directory with `filecount='ls -l ${survey_dir}${survey_category} | wc -l'`. I want to use `filecount` to generate the filename of the next survey. So if the `survey_category` directory has two files, the new filename will be `3.php`.

Before starting the heredoc, I issue the following variables and commands:

```
filecount=$((filecount+1))
newfile="${wd}${catg}/${filecount}.php"
cat > ${newfile} <<-EOF
...
EOF
```

When I execute the script the `cat` command yields the error message 'Bad substitution'.

I tried to overcome this by quoting the `<<-EOF`: like `<<-'EOF'`, however I use a lot of variable substitutions in php, so this solution can't be implemented.

I checked if `ls -l /bin/bash` actually links to `bash` and not `dash` or another `sh` shell.

I checked if my 'shebang' is `#!/bin/bash` and not `#!/bin/sh`. Checked ok.

Furthermore I tried to use single and double quotes on the variable `${newfile}`: to no avail.

Debug info `#!/bin/bash -x`:

```
: bad substitution
+ [[ 1: == \2\: ]]
+ [[ 1: == \3\: ]]
+ [[ 1: == \4\: ]]
```

My question is:  how to write a heredoc to a dynamically created file?

Code that is causing the problem:

```
    echo -e "Your question please:"
    read -e rvraag
    rvraag="${rvraag//\"/\^}"
    salt=`date +"%s"`
    filecount=`ls -l ${wd}${catg} | wc -l`
    filecount=$((filecount+1))
    newfile="${wd}${catg}/${filecount}.php"
    cat > ${newfile} <<-EOF

    <?php
     session_start();
    \$st_code =\$_SESSION['studentnr'];
    \$cursuscode ="${catg}";
    \$rdir="/var/www/qqlq.org/www/gen_enq/";
    require_once \$rdir.'/inc/error_reporting.inc';
    require_once \$rdir.'/src/clsQuestionProgress.class.php';
    \$myQuestionProgress = new clsQuestionProgress();
    \$myQuestionProgress->fCreateQuestionProgress( \$st_code, \$cursuscode );
    require_once \$rdir.'/inc/header.inc';
    require_once \$rdir.'/src/clsWriteProgress.class.php';
    echo "<div class='container'><hr>
    Vraag ${catg} ${filecount}<h4> ${rvraag}</h4><br><br>
    <form name='qradio' action =".\$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']." method= 'POST'>
    <div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='${catg}${salt}'

    value='1'>${answ1}<label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='${catg}${salt}' value='2'>${answ2}<label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='${catg}${salt}' value='3'>${answ3}<label></div>
        <div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='${catg}${salt}' value='4'>${answ4}<label></div>
       <input type='submit' class='btn btn-warning' name='btnCancel${salt}' value='Go Back'>
       <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name='btn${catg}${salt}' value='Ok'>
    </form>
    <hr></div>";
    if (  \$_POST['${catg}${salt}'] == "${answok}" && isset( $_POST['btn${catg}${salt}'] ) ){
          \$myProgress = new clsWriteProgress();
          \$tablename = 'q'.\$st_code.\$cursuscode;
          \$myProgress->fSetProgress( \$tablename, \$_SESSION["leerjaar"],$st_code,\$cursuscode,"${rvraag}",1 );
          \$nextpage=${filecount)+1;
          echo '<script>location.replace("'.\${nextpage}.php.'");</script>';
    }//end if

     if (  \$_POST['${catg}${salt}'] !== "${answok}" && isset( \$_POST['btn${catg}${salt}'] ) ){

          \$tablename = 'q'.\$st_code.\$cursuscode;
          \$myProgress = new clsWriteProgress();
          \$myProgress->fSetProgress( \$tablename, \$_SESSION["leerjaar"],\$st_code,\$cursuscode,"${rvraag}",0 );
          \$nextpage=${filecount)+1;
          echo '<script>location.replace("'.${nextpage}.php.'");</script>';
    }//end if

    if ( isset( \$_POST['btnCancel${salt}'] ) ){
            echo '<script>location.replace("../../studyoverview.php" );</script>';

    }//end if
EOF
```

Comment: This is suspect - `cat > ${newfile} <<-EOF` - Remove the dash

Comment: @Ed Heal: when I remove the dash an error message appears: `warning: here-document at line 57 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')`. I need the dash to skip tabs in the script..

Comment: Can you post whole code? Removing the dash shouldn't lead to such error.

Comment: The code:`wd="/var/www/example.com/www/survey/"
                filecount='ls -l ${wd}${catg} | wc -l'
                catg="survey01";
                filecount=$((filecount+1))
                newfile="${wd}${catg}/${filecount}.php"
                echo "${newfile}"
                cat > ${newfile} <<-EOF
                <?php
                .....
 ?>EOF`

Comment: @nsilent22 It does if the line with the closing `EOF` starts with tabs.

Comment: @kzpm Can you [edit] the question to add the code?

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Oh, yes, you are right.

Comment: Based on the error message, I suspect the problem is *within* the here-doc, due to improper escaping, but you have to add the contents of the here-doc.

Comment: [**Don't parse ls**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to generate your file count. Instead, avoid spawning the subshell. Read an pattern expansion (glob) into an array, and count the elements: `junk=( ${survey_dir}${survey_category}/* ); filecount=${#junk[@]}` ... or use a for loop: `for junk in ${survey_dir}${survey_category}/*; do ((filecount++)); done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in Benjamin W's comment, the problem was caused within the php code that should have been written to a file.

In my code I wrote
`$nextpage=${filecount)+1;` Mark the parenthesis!

It should have been: 
`$nextpage=${filecount}+1;`

The strategy to analyse the 'Bad substitution' error, was to start with an empty bash script.
After that I wrote the heredoc skeleton testing it line by line. 
When no error returned, I pasted the following line and so on until I reached the '$filecount}+1' expression.

Problem solved, thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the syntax for a heredoc is << not <<-

Comment: From `man bash`: If the redirection operator  is  <<-,  then  all  leading  tab  characters  are
       stripped from input lines and the line containing delimiter.  This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.

Comment: @Todd: the dash `-` is for ignoring tabs in the result file. See my comment on Ed Heal

Answer (score 0):

@kzpm: Basing on code you provided this works for me:

```
!/bin/bash

wd="/tmp/workdir/"
catg="survey01"
mkdir -p ${wd}${catg}
filecount=`ls ${wd}${catg} | wc -l`
filecount=$((filecount+1))
newfile="${wd}${catg}/${filecount}.php"
echo "${newfile}"
cat > ${newfile} <<-EOF
<?php ..... ?>
EOF
```

Changes i made:
1. Backticks for `ls` (single quotes in your code and probably that was the case)
2. Moving setting `catg` value at the beginning (you were declaring it after filecount)

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite this as a PHP shell script, if you're working in an environment that you know has PHP installed. Seriously, some headaches just aren't worth your time. Bash is nice if you're looking for something quick and dirty, but as soon as you start throwing certain characters (chiefly dollar signs) into the mix, you're setting yourself up for a lot of debugging.

Details on using PHP from the command line:
http://www.php.net/cli

You can get user input at the command line using:

```
echo "Your question please: ";
$question = fgets(STDIN);
```

(Some people will no doubt chime in that Python or Perl are better bets, but since you're outputting PHP anyway it makes sense to stick with a single langauge.)